# Mongoose, saving the result of a find appears to do nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas, `FinishedGame` and `PlayingGame`. Both schemas are identical. When I close a game I'd like to copy the `PlayingGame` to the `FinishedGame` collection and then delete the `PlayingGame`. The code right now doesn't appear to throw an error but it also doesn't add anything to `FinishedGame`. When I open shell an run `show collections` I only see `playinggames` and `system.indexes`.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Heres the code that is run when I want to close a game:

```
console.log('finding ', gameId);
PlayingGame.findById(gameId, function(err, game) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw 'Problem finding game when closing';
    }

    console.log(game);
    // if game found, move PlayingGame to FinishedGame emit game closed to room
    if (game) {
        console.log('Saving game to finished games');
        var finishedGame = new FinishedGame(game);
        finishedGame.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw 'Problem saving finished game when moving playing game to finished game';
            console.log('Successfuly saved to finish game');
            game.remove(function(err) {
                if (err) throw 'Problem removing from playing games';

                socket.leave('game:' + gameId);
                // send message to room that the game has been closed
                io.to('game:' + gameId).emit('game closed');
            });
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Maybe `game` is not found by id? Do you see `Saving game to finished games` message in console?

Comment: this worked @JohnnyHK if you post answer I can select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `toObject()` on `game` before passing it to the `FinishedGame` constructor as it's expecting a plain JS object, not a Mongoose doc instance.

So change that line to:

```
var finishedGame = new FinishedGame(game.toObject());
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, i'm agree with johny's answer. you could also use 
var gameClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(game));
var finishedGame = new FinishedGame(gameClone);